# Magento Installation SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory error

Tags: php, magento, xampp

I am a newbie at LAMPP enviroment and I installed XAMPP for installing Magento.
Everthing was going fine till "Add database" step of Magento installation. I created database which is called 'magento' from phpMyAdmin and I am getting this error. I made many searches on it most of people talked about connection type.
I couldn't handle that point. Is there anyone who know how to figure socketing for magento.
To see screenshoot please click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wy4o3.jpg).Thank you from now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I handled the problem by changing '`localhost`' to '`127.0.0.1`'.

First go to folder where you installed the xampp and find out `config.inc.php`. (mine is `/opt/lamp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`.

After take a look to `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';`. 
If it is `localhost` change by '`127.0.0.1`'

Comment: you can also modify `app/etc/env.php` file to update host

Answer (score 3):

Just try to restart the MySql DB service

```
service mysql start
```

It worked for me..

Answer (score 2):

for mac with MAMP, it will work

```
ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Just change 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' if you are working in your local machine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is the same solution as in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42484822/2227743).